# CodeIgniter Hello World MVC with two models

Tags: php, codeigniter

My CI controller looks like this:

```
 // Controller.
 class Hello extends CI_Controller
 {
     public function one($name)
     {
         $this->load->model("hello_model");

         $profile = $this->hello_model->getProfile("Me");
         //$profile2 = $this->hello_model->otherAction();

         $this->load->view('header');

         $data = array("name" => $name);
         $data['profile'] = $profile;
         $this->load->view('one.html', $data);
     }
 }
```

and here is/are the model(s)

```
 class Hello_model extends CI_Model
 {
     public function getProfile($name)
     {
         return array("fullName" => "Martin", "Age" => 28);
     }
 }

 class Hello_model_2 extends CI_Model
 {
     public function otherAction()
     {
         echo "Data";
     }
 }
```

When I enable the `$profile2` statement and visit the controller in the browser, I find this error message in Apache Error log:

```
[Mon Apr 01 ...] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]
PHP Fatal error: 
Call to undefined method Hello_model::otherAction() in 
/.../CodeIgniter_2.1.3/application/controllers/Hello.php on line x
```

where `x` is the line of the `profile2` statement.

Can I not have two classes in a "`model`"-file?
Btw, what are `.php` files called in CI-speak? Modules?

Comment: CI loads each Class from file with the same name.. even if you have 100 classes in 1 file it will load only the one with the name as your file name.. 
So you should make files for each model / controller etc you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Each file must have one model only.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Instead create another method in same class like-

```
class Hello_model extends CI_Model
 {
     public function getProfile($name)
     {
         return array("fullName" => "Martin", "Age" => 28);
     }

     public function otherAction()
     {
         echo "Data";
     }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the ref although I can not read anywhere explicitly that only one class per model file is allowed!

Answer (score 1):

you have to create two seprate class files

hello_model.php

```
 class Hello_model extends CI_Model
 {
     public function getProfile($name)
     {
         return array("fullName" => "Martin", "Age" => 28);
     }
 }
```

hello_model_2.php

```
 class Hello_model_2 extends CI_Model
 {
     public function otherAction()
     {
         echo "Data";
     }
 }
```

and call in controller

```
     $this->load->model("hello_model");
     $this->load->model("Hello_model_2");

     $profile = $this->hello_model->getProfile("Me");
     $profile2 = $this->hello_model_2->otherAction();
```

or

**you can use multiple methods in your model**

Comment: is that `CI` only or is that PHP general?

Comment: this is for CI only, not a php

Answer (score 0):

You can try with "EXTENDS" of one model into another like

```
class Hello_model extends CI_Model
{
   public function getProfile($name)
   {
      return array("fullName" => "Martin", "Age" => 28);
   }

   public function otherAction()
   {
      echo "Data";
   }
}
```

then create second model like Hello_model_2.php

```
class Hello_model_2 extends Hello_model
{ 
    //Here access those from Hello_model
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create 2 models file `Hello_model` and `Hello_model_2` then also load `Hello_model_2` like this

```
class Hello extends CI_Controller
{
 public function one($name)
 {
     $this->load->model("hello_model");
     $this->load->model("hello_model_2");

     $profile = $this->hello_model->getProfile("Me");
     $profile2 = $this->hello_model_2->otherAction();

     $this->load->view('header');

     $data = array("name" => $name);
     $data['profile'] = $profile;
     $this->load->view('one.html', $data);
 }
}
```

And if you are using one model and two function then u should use this code into your model

```
class Hello_model extends CI_Model
{
   public function getProfile($name)
   {
       return array("fullName" => "Martin", "Age" => 28);
   }

   public function otherAction()
   {
      echo "Data";
   }
}
```

Hope you understand.